# How to change MIME type through HTML?

Tags: html, css, mime

I am trying to create a reponsive navbar, but when I trying to link css, it did not work, as it threw the error:

> The stylesheet http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/index.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Things I have fixed

- Tried using the mime node module
- Tried removing the `/` before the linking

I try linking the CSS with:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/index.css">
```

Comment: What kind of web server are you using?

Comment: @VinceV. Node.js express application